# How to use a subview with a different model than that of the main view?

Tags: c#, razor, partial-views

I want to use a partial view to represent the rows of a table:

```
// SomeItem.cshtml
@model SomeItemModel
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.SomeField)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.AnotherField)
    </td>
</tr>
```

And call it from a view representing a page containing that table:

```
// SomeCollection.cshtml
@model SomeCollection
...
<table><tbody>
@foreach (TipoDocumentoModel item in Model) {
    Html.Partial("SomeItem", item);
}>
</tbody></table>
...
```

But it doesn't work. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `Html.Partial` returns a `MvcHtmlString` without writing anything to the page.

You need to add an `@` to render the `MvcHtmlString` to the page.